# Do not want to keep image outside of jar file in same folder

Tags: java, swing

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Image frstWinBackg = new ImageIcon("new.jpg").getImage();
    g.drawImage(frstWinBackg, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
}
```

I am drawing an image file as [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) background through above code. When I make executable jar file of my project, I have to keep that image file in same folder. Is there any way to compact this image file inside jar file as I think providing image file along with jar file is not a good idea.

Comment: No, you don't have to keep the image file in the same folder. You can keep it anywhere you like: inside the JAR file, for example. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: When I run the jar file, the image do not appear. But if I keep image file in the same folder as jar file, this image is shown as background. But I want that if I run the jar file, the image to appear as background without keeping it in same folder.

Comment: “When I run the jar file, the image do[es] not appear.” Yes, because an entry inside a .jar file is not a separate file.  Use `ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("new.jpg"))` to read it instead.  And read it *once,* in your constructor;  a paintComponent method can be called *several times per second,* so reading in a file every time you paint would have a noticeable effect on performance.

Comment: Thanks a million @VGR. It works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Image frstWinBackg = new ImageIcon("new.jpg").getImage();
    g.drawImage(frstWinBackg, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
}
```

In this code, image file is read inside **paintComponent()** method. As **paintComponent()** method can be called several times in a second, it searches for image file every time. So, to make appearing the image, image file has to be kept in the same folder of jar file.

If we don't want to provide image file externally, we must read image inside the constructor and draw it by **paintComponent()** method.

e.g. In constructor, to read image file:

```
Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("resources/new.jpg"));
```

Then, **paintComponent()** method will be:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just store images inside JAR as resources. This [tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/) explains how to do it. When you read it I think you can adopt it for your build system (Maven, Gradle, etc.).